# Unable to find rendering system

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I got following error messages.
What's the problem?
I compiled the code on Ubuntu 12.04 and just run it.

```
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.0.2
Copyright (C) 2011 Nate Koenig, John Hsu, Andrew Howard, and contributors.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://localhost:11345
Exception [RenderEngine.cc:471] unable to find rendering system

Error [Rendering.cc:37] Failed to load the Rendering engine subsystem
unable to find rendering system
Exception [RenderEngine.cc:471] unable to find rendering system

Exception [Sensors.cc:39] Unable to load the rendering engine

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'gazebo::common::Exception'
Aborted (core dumped)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44009/unable-to-find-rendering-system/) by [Jeongseok](https://answers.ros.org/users/3214/jeongseok/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-09-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2012-09-17**:
Why aren't you using the pre-packaged version of gazebo?

**Comment by [Jeongseok](https://answers.ros.org/users/3214/jeongseok/) on 2012-09-17**:
I'm just trying to understand the inside code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Jeongseok,  can you confirm tht this was due to lack of direct rendering as indicated by glxinfo?

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2013-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1